# Reading in array from text file

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to read in an array of baseball player names and various stats that is delimited with a ';'. 
Here are 2 lines so my example code will make sense

```
Abreu, J;CWS;1B;30;101;0.29
Altuve, J;HOU;2B;15;66;0.313
```

Currently I am reading the file into an array where each line is in its own index in the array with the following code:

```
    public static void fillArray()
    {
        string[] linesInFile = File.ReadAllLines(GlobalVariables.filePath);
        //EACH LINE IS A STRING AT THIS POINT
        foreach (string s in linesInFile)
        {
            string[] items = s.Split(';');
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(items[i]);
                //Console.WriteLine(items[1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The only issue is I'm new to C# and don't know how to access this filled array from a different method so I can sort it and display various info etc.

I've searched all permutations I can think of on google, but I can't find any relevant answers.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are each of the stats called?

Comment: @Enigmativity Player;Team;Position;Home runs;RBI;Batting average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the signature of your `fillArray` method to return your `array`. Given you sample code, you'll need a two dimensional array, because you have multiple lines so a [jagged array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) would be a good choice if players' stats are not fixed (some players may have fewer or more stats). Alternatively instead of an array you can return a list of lists (`List<List<string>>`) which are more flexible than arrays. So your code returning a jagged array will look like this:

```
public static string[][] fillArray()
{
    string[] linesInFile = File.ReadAllLines(GlobalVariables.filePath);
    string[][] result = new string[linesInFile.Length][];
    int index = 0;
    //EACH LINE IS A STRING AT THIS POINT
    foreach (string s in linesInFile)
    {
        string[] items = s.Split(';');
        result[index++] = items;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note that it is more preferable/readable to return the array instead of having a global one and change it in your method.

Answer (score 1):

> how to access this filled array from a different method

You would either need to pass the array into the other method as a parameter or you would need to declare the variable outside of the method to up its scope.

Answer (score 1):

One way is by creating a list of those arrays outside of the method `fillArray`

```
List<string[]> itemsList = new List<string[]>(); //declare this outside of the method
public static void fillArray()
{
    string[] linesInFile = File.ReadAllLines(GlobalVariables.filePath);
    //EACH LINE IS A STRING AT THIS POINT
    foreach (string s in linesInFile)
    {
        string[] items = s.Split(';');
        itemsList.Add(items); //add the list in the itemsList
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(items[i]);
            //Console.WriteLine(items[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply use it in other method like this:

```
public void otherMethod(){
    string[] itemsAtZero = itemsList[0]; //your first string[] items
    string[] itemsAtOne = itemsList[1]; //your second string[] items
    //and so on...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go about it like this:

```
Player[] players =
(
    from line in File.ReadAllLines(GlobalVariables.filePath)
    let parts = line.Split(';')
    select new Player(
        parts[0], parts[1], parts[2],
        int.Parse(parts[3]), int.Parse(parts[4]),
        double.Parse(parts[5]))
).ToArray();
```

You'll get this result:

[image: players]

You'll need this `Player` class too:

```
public sealed class Player : IEquatable<Player>
{
    private readonly string _Name;
    private readonly string _Team;
    private readonly string _Position;
    private readonly int _HomeRuns;
    private readonly int _Rbi;
    private readonly double _BattingAverage;

    public string Name { get { return _Name; } }
    public string Team { get { return _Team; } }
    public string Position { get { return _Position; } }
    public int HomeRuns { get { return _HomeRuns; } }
    public int Rbi { get { return _Rbi; } }
    public double BattingAverage { get { return _BattingAverage; } }

    public Player(string Name, string Team, string Position, int HomeRuns, int Rbi, double BattingAverage)
    {
        _Name = Name;
        _Team = Team;
        _Position = Position;
        _HomeRuns = HomeRuns;
        _Rbi = Rbi;
        _BattingAverage = BattingAverage;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Player)
            return Equals((Player)obj);
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Player obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(_Name, obj._Name)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(_Team, obj._Team)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(_Position, obj._Position)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<int>.Default.Equals(_HomeRuns, obj._HomeRuns)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<int>.Default.Equals(_Rbi, obj._Rbi)) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<double>.Default.Equals(_BattingAverage, obj._BattingAverage)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(_Name);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(_Team);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(_Position);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<int>.Default.GetHashCode(_HomeRuns);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<int>.Default.GetHashCode(_Rbi);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<double>.Default.GetHashCode(_BattingAverage);
        return hash;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{{ Name = {0}, Team = {1}, Position = {2}, HomeRuns = {3}, Rbi = {4}, BattingAverage = {5} }}", _Name, _Team, _Position, _HomeRuns, _Rbi, _BattingAverage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to *return* the array read:

```
  public static String[][] fillArray() {
    return File
      .ReadLines(GlobalVariables.filePath)
      .Select(line => line.Split(';')) 
      .ToArray(); // usually not necessary, but question requies array 
  }
```

And so you can, say, print out the array form some other method:

```
  Console.Write(String.Join(Ebvironment.NewLine, fillArray()
    .OrderBy(items => items[1]) // Let's sort the array by second column
    .ThenBy(items => items[0])  // ..and by 1st column on tie
    .Select(items => String.Join(","))));
```

A better approach is to return a special designed class `Player` instead of `String[]` like this:

```
  public static Player[] fillArray() {
    return File
      .ReadLines(GlobalVariables.filePath)
      .Select(line => line.Split(';')) 
      .Select(items => new Player(items[0], items[1], items[2]) {
         HomeRuns = Int.Parse(items[3], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
         RBI = Double.Parse(items[4], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
         Batting = Double.Parse(items[5], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
      })
      .ToArray(); // usually not necessary, but question requies array 
  }
```

and the sample report will be

```
  Console.Write(String.Join(Ebvironment.NewLine, fillArray()
    .OrderBy(player => player.Team) 
    .ThenBy(player => player.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this... you can find lots of good tutorials online to help you build up your foundation on C#

```
static void Main()
{
  List<MyObject> myListOfObjects = fillArray();
  DisplaySortedArray(myListOfObjects);
  Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void DisplaySortedArray(List<MyObject> myListOfObjects)
{
  foreach(var myObject in myListOfObjects)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(myObject.Property1);
      Console.WriteLine(myObject.Property2);
      Console.WriteLine(myObject.Property3);
      Console.WriteLine(myObject.Property4);
      Console.WriteLine(myObject.Property5);
      Console.WriteLine(myObject.Property6);
  }
}

public static List<MyObject> fillArray()
{
    string[] linesInFile = File.ReadAllLines(GlobalVariables.filePath);
    List<MyObject> myListOfObjects = new List<MyObject>();

    foreach (string s in linesInFile)
    {
        string[] items = s.Split(';');
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        myObject.Property1 = items[0];
        myObject.Property2 = items[1];
        myObject.Property3 = items[2];
        myObject.Property4 = items[3];
        myObject.Property5 = items[4];
        myObject.Property6 = items[5];
        myListOfObjects.Add(myObject);
    }

    return myListOfObjects;
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string Property1 {get;set;}
    public string Property2 {get;set;}
    public string Property3 {get;set;}
    public string Property4 {get;set;}
    public string Property5 {get;set;}
    public string Property6 {get;set;}
}
```